# Discord Bot error 10062 when checking for channel name when a slash command is sent by a user

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am making a discord bot (in javascript) for a study server with my friends, and there is a functionality I'm working on in which you can add people's phone numbers, but only in a specific channel. If was working fine until I added the check for is the particular channel, but it started to give me this error since it started to do that. Here are the files as the file structure:

```
Study Bot
 + node-modules
 + src
    + index.js
    + register-commands.js
 + .env
 + .gitignore
 + package-lock.json
 + package.json
```

Before giving the files, here is the error that I'm receiving:

```
D:\Discord Bots\Study Bot\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:640
      throw new DiscordAPIError(data, "code" in data ? data.code : data.error, status, method, url, requestData);
            ^

DiscordAPIError[10062]: Unknown interaction
    at handleErrors (D:\Discord Bots\Study Bot\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:640:13)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async BurstHandler.runRequest (D:\Discord Bots\Study Bot\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:736:23)
    at async REST.request (D:\Discord Bots\Study Bot\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:1387:22)
    at async ChatInputCommandInteraction.reply (D:\Discord Bots\Study Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\InteractionResponses.js:111:5) {    
  requestBody: {
    files: [],
    json: {
      type: 4,
      data: {
        content: "<@807505163237195846> added `Me`'s Number: `1234567890`",     
        tts: false,
        nonce: undefined,
        embeds: undefined,
        components: undefined,
        username: undefined,
        avatar_url: undefined,
        allowed_mentions: undefined,
        flags: undefined,
        message_reference: undefined,
        attachments: undefined,
        sticker_ids: undefined,
        thread_name: undefined
      }
    }
  },
  rawError: { message: 'Unknown interaction', code: 10062 },
  code: 10062,
  status: 404,
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://discord.com/api/v10/interactions/1129315235019366472/aW50ZXJhY3Rpb246MTEyOTMxNTIzNTAxOTM2NjQ3MjpYRE5LV3htMVZDanFLRVV4eWdIWk9DMnBqT2RVZkFkV014MVFuWFo2aUhtZmYxMmdTRkttNTFIeUtBMXhlU0xpUzhINnNHblFsbUxkMktZdkV2dDR0TThtWnBpemR2ZVMzUk5yNzM4V3Y5N0duMWV3ck1mUE1tZldZeVVvdTkzQg/callback'
}

Node.js v18.16.1
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

`index.js`:

```js
require("dotenv").config();
const { Client, IntentsBitField } = require("discord.js");

const bot = new Client({
    intents: [
        IntentsBitField.Flags.Guilds,
        IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMembers,
        IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMessages,
        IntentsBitField.Flags.MessageContent,
    ],
});

bot.on("ready", c => {
    console.log(`✅ ${c.user.tag} is online!`);
});

bot.on("messageCreate", msg => {
    if(msg.author.bot) return;

    if(msg.content === "hello") {
        msg.reply("hello");
    }
});

bot.on("interactionCreate", interaction => {
    if(!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;

    // if(interaction.commandName === "hey") {
    //  interaction.reply("hey");
    // }

    // if(interaction.commands)

    switch(interaction.commandName) {
        case "hey": {
            interaction.reply("hey");
        } break;
        case "add": {
            const num1 = interaction.options.get("first-number").value;
            const num2 = interaction.options.get("second-number").value;
            interaction.reply(`The sum is ${num1 + num2}`);
        } break;
        case "add-phone-number": {
            const numberOfWho = interaction.options.get("number-of").value;
            const number = interaction.options.get("number").value;

            console.log(number);
            console.log(numberOfWho);
            console.log(typeof(number));

            if(`${number}`.length !== 10 || /^\+91/.exec(String.toString(number))) {
                interaction.reply(`The number entered is not valid, please re-check and enter again: \`${number}\``);
                break;
            }

            if(interaction.channel.name !== "phone-numbers") {
                interaction.reply(`Error: You are in the wrong channel, please add the number in <#1129309284438638593>`);
            }

            let numberOfWho_formatted = numberOfWho[0].toUpperCase();
            for(let i = 0; i < numberOfWho.length - 1; i++) {
                numberOfWho_formatted += numberOfWho[i + 1];
            }

            interaction.reply(`<@${interaction.user.id}> added \`${numberOfWho_formatted}\`'s Number: \`${number}\``);
        } break;
        default: break;
    }
});

bot.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

(I'm just learning making discord bots, so the commands such as /hey and /add were just when I was learning, they will be removed in the future)

`register-commands.js`:

```js
require("dotenv").config();
const { REST, Routes, ApplicationCommandOptionType } = require("discord.js");

const commands = [
    {
        name: "hey",
        description: "replies with hey",
    },
    {
        name: "add-phone-number",
        description: "Adds a phone number",
        options: [
            {
                name: "number-of",
                description: "A number of whome?",
                type: ApplicationCommandOptionType.String,
                required: true,
            },
            {
                name: "number",
                description: "Please enter the number... (without the +91)",
                type: ApplicationCommandOptionType.String,
                required: true,
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "add",
        description: "adds two numbers",
        options: [
            {
                name: "first-number",
                description: "The first number",
                type: ApplicationCommandOptionType.Number,
                required: true,
                choices: [
                    {
                        name: "1",
                        value: 1,
                    },
                    {
                        name: "2",
                        value: 2,
                    },
                    {
                        name: "3",
                        value: 3,
                    },
                    {
                        name: "4",
                        value: 4,
                    },
                    {
                        name: "5",
                        value: 5,
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                name: "second-number",
                description: "The second number",
                type: ApplicationCommandOptionType.Number,
                required: true,
            },
        ],
    },
];

const rest = new REST({ version: '10' }).setToken(process.env.TOKEN);

(async () => {
    try {
        console.log("Registering slash commands...");

        await rest.put(Routes.applicationGuildCommands(process.env.BOT_ID, process.env.GUILD_ID), { body: commands });

        console.log("Slash commands were registered successfully!");
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(`There was an error: ${error}`);
    }
})();
```

`package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "study-bot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "register": "node src/register-commands.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^14.11.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1"
  }
}
```

(I also have installed nodemon on my computer and use it to live-run the bot)

`package-lock.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "study-bot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "lockfileVersion": 3,
  "requires": true,
  "packages": {
    "": {
      "name": "study-bot",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "license": "ISC",
      "dependencies": {
        "discord.js": "^14.11.0",
        "dotenv": "^16.3.1"
      }
    },
    "node_modules/@discordjs/builders": {
      "version": "1.6.3",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@discordjs/builders/-/builders-1.6.3.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-CTCh8NqED3iecTNuiz49mwSsrc2iQb4d0MjMdmS/8pb69Y4IlzJ/DIy/p5GFlgOrFbNO2WzMHkWKQSiJ3VNXaw==",
      "dependencies": {
        "@discordjs/formatters": "^0.3.1",
        "@discordjs/util": "^0.3.1",
        "@sapphire/shapeshift": "^3.8.2",
        "discord-api-types": "^0.37.41",
        "fast-deep-equal": "^3.1.3",
        "ts-mixer": "^6.0.3",
        "tslib": "^2.5.0"
      },
      "engines": {
        "node": ">=16.9.0"
      }
    },
    "node_modules/@discordjs/collection": {
      "version": "1.5.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@discordjs/collection/-/collection-1.5.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-aWEc9DCf3TMDe9iaJoOnO2+JVAjeRNuRxPZQA6GVvBf+Z3gqUuWYBy2NWh4+5CLYq5uoc3MOvUQ5H5m8CJBqOA==",
      "engines": {
        "node": ">=16.9.0"
      }
    },
    "node_modules/@discordjs/formatters": {
      "version": "0.3.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@discordjs/formatters/-/formatters-0.3.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-M7X4IGiSeh4znwcRGcs+49B5tBkNDn4k5bmhxJDAUhRxRHTiFAOTVUNQ6yAKySu5jZTnCbSvTYHW3w0rAzV1MA==",
      "dependencies": {
        "discord-api-types": "^0.37.41"
      },
      "engines": {
        "node": ">=16.9.0"
      }
    },
    "node_modules/@discordjs/rest": {
      "version": "1.7.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@discordjs/rest/-/rest-1.7.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-Ofa9UqT0U45G/eX86cURQnX7gzOJLG2oC28VhIk/G6IliYgQF7jFByBJEykPSHE4MxPhqCleYvmsrtfKh1nYmQ==",
      "dependencies": {
        "@discordjs/collection": "^1.5.1",
        "@discordjs/util": "^0.3.0",
        "@sapphire/async-queue": "^1.5.0",
        "@sapphire/snowflake": "^3.4.2",
        "discord-api-types": "^0.37.41",
        "file-type": "^18.3.0",
        "tslib": "^2.5.0",
        "undici": "^5.22.0"
      },
      "engines": {
        "node": ">=16.9.0"
      }
    },
    "node_modules/@discordjs/util": {
      "version": "0.3.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@discordjs/util/-/util-0.3.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-HxXKYKg7vohx2/OupUN/4Sd02Ev3PBJ5q0gtjdcvXb0ErCva8jNHWfe/v5sU3UKjIB/uxOhc+TDOnhqffj9pRA==",
      "engines": {
        "node": ">=16.9.0"
      }
    },
    "node_modules/@discordjs/ws": {
      "version": "0.8.3",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@discordjs/ws/-/ws-0.8.3.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-hcYtppanjHecbdNyCKQNH2I4RP9UrphDgmRgLYrATEQF1oo4sYSve7ZmGsBEXSzH72MO2tBPdWSThunbxUVk0g==",
      "dependencies": {
        "@discordjs/collection": "^1.5.1",
        "@discordjs/rest": "^1.7.1",
        "@discordjs/util": "^0.3.1",
        "@sapphire/async-queue": "^1.5.0",
        "@types/ws": "^8.5.4",
        "@vladfrangu/async_event_emitter": "^2.2.1",
        "discord-api-types": "^0.37.41",
        "tslib": "^2.5.0",
        "ws": "^8.13.0"
      },
      "engines": {
        "node": ">=16.9.0"
      }
    },
    "node_modules/@sapphire/async-queue": {
      "version": "1.5.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@sapphire/async-queue/-/async-queue-1.5.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-JkLdIsP8fPAdh9ZZjrbHWR/+mZj0wvKS5ICibcLrRI1j84UmLMshx5n9QmL8b95d4onJ2xxiyugTgSAX7AalmA==",
      "engines": {
        "node": ">=v14.0.0",
        "npm": ">=7.0.0"
      }
    },
    "node_modules/@sapphire/shapeshift": {
      "version": "3.9.2",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@sapphire/shapeshift/-/shapeshift-3.9.2.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-YRbCXWy969oGIdqR/wha62eX8GNHsvyYi0Rfd4rNW6tSVVa8p0ELiMEuOH/k8rgtvRoM+EMV7Csqz77YdwiDpA==",
      "dependencies": {
        "fast-deep-equal": "^3.1.3",
        "lodash": "^4.17.21"
      },
      "engines": {
        "node": ">=v14.0.0",
        "npm": ">=7.0.0"
      }
    },
    "node_modules/@sapphire/snowflake": {
      "version": "3.5.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@sapphire/snowflake/-/snowflake-3.5.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-BxcYGzgEsdlG0dKAyOm0ehLGm2CafIrfQTZGWgkfKYbj+pNNsorZ7EotuZukc2MT70E0UbppVbtpBrqpzVzjNA==",
      "engines": {
        "node": ">=v14.0.0",
        "npm": ">=7.0.0"
      }
    },
    "node_modules/@tokenizer/token": {
      "version": "0.3.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@tokenizer/token/-/token-0.3.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-OvjF+z51L3ov0OyAU0duzsYuvO01PH7x4t6DJx+guahgTnBHkhJdG7soQeTSFLWN3efnHyibZ4Z8l2EuWwJN3A=="
    },
    "node_modules/@types/node": {
      "version": "20.4.2",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@types/node/-/node-20.4.2.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-Dd0BYtWgnWJKwO1jkmTrzofjK2QXXcai0dmtzvIBhcA+RsG5h8R3xlyta0kGOZRNfL9GuRtb1knmPEhQrePCEw=="
    },
    "node_modules/@types/ws": {
      "version": "8.5.5",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@types/ws/-/ws-8.5.5.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-lwhs8hktwxSjf9UaZ9tG5M03PGogvFaH8gUgLNbN9HKIg0dvv6q+gkSuJ8HN4/VbyxkuLzCjlN7GquQ0gUJfIg==",
      "dependencies": {
        "@types/node": "*"
      }
    },
    "node_modules/@vladfrangu/async_event_emitter": {
      "version": "2.2.2",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@vladfrangu/async_event_emitter/-/async_event_emitter-2.2.2.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-HIzRG7sy88UZjBJamssEczH5q7t5+axva19UbZLO6u0ySbYPrwzWiXBcC0WuHyhKKoeCyneH+FvYzKQq/zTtkQ==",
      "engines": {
        "node": ">=v14.0.0",
        "npm": ">=7.0.0"
      }
    },
    "node_modules/busboy": {
      "version": "1.6.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/busboy/-/busboy-1.6.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-8SFQbg/0hQ9xy3UNTB0YEnsNBbWfhf7RtnzpL7TkBiTBRfrQ9Fxcnz7VJsleJpyp6rVLvXiuORqjlHi5q+PYuA==",
      "dependencies": {
        "streamsearch": "^1.1.0"
      },
      "engines": {
        "node": ">=10.16.0"
      }
    },
    "node_modules/discord-api-types": {
      "version": "0.37.48",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/discord-api-types/-/discord-api-types-0.37.48.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-vu2NQJD7SZRjpKDC2DPNsxTz34KS53OrotA+LGRW6mcyT55Hjqu66aRrouzjYhea7tllL9I7rvWVX7bg3aT2AQ=="
    },
    "node_modules/discord.js": {
      "version": "14.11.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/discord.js/-/discord.js-14.11.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-CkueWYFQ28U38YPR8HgsBR/QT35oPpMbEsTNM30Fs8loBIhnA4s70AwQEoy6JvLcpWWJO7GY0y2BUzZmuBMepQ==",
      "dependencies": {
        "@discordjs/builders": "^1.6.3",
        "@discordjs/collection": "^1.5.1",
        "@discordjs/formatters": "^0.3.1",
        "@discordjs/rest": "^1.7.1",
        "@discordjs/util": "^0.3.1",
        "@discordjs/ws": "^0.8.3",
        "@sapphire/snowflake": "^3.4.2",
        "@types/ws": "^8.5.4",
        "discord-api-types": "^0.37.41",
        "fast-deep-equal": "^3.1.3",
        "lodash.snakecase": "^4.1.1",
        "tslib": "^2.5.0",
        "undici": "^5.22.0",
        "ws": "^8.13.0"
      },
      "engines": {
        "node": ">=16.9.0"
      }
    },
    "node_modules/dotenv": {
      "version": "16.3.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/dotenv/-/dotenv-16.3.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-IPzF4w4/Rd94bA9imS68tZBaYyBWSCE47V1RGuMrB94iyTOIEwRmVL2x/4An+6mETpLrKJ5hQkB8W4kFAadeIQ==",
      "engines": {
        "node": ">=12"
      },
      "funding": {
        "url": "https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv?sponsor=1"
      }
    },
    "node_modules/fast-deep-equal": {
      "version": "3.1.3",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/fast-deep-equal/-/fast-deep-equal-3.1.3.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-f3qQ9oQy9j2AhBe/H9VC91wLmKBCCU/gDOnKNAYG5hswO7BLKj09Hc5HYNz9cGI++xlpDCIgDaitVs03ATR84Q=="
    },
    "node_modules/file-type": {
      "version": "18.5.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/file-type/-/file-type-18.5.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-yvpl5U868+V6PqXHMmsESpg6unQ5GfnPssl4dxdJudBrr9qy7Fddt7EVX1VLlddFfe8Gj9N7goCZH22FXuSQXQ==",
      "dependencies": {
        "readable-web-to-node-stream": "^3.0.2",
        "strtok3": "^7.0.0",
        "token-types": "^5.0.1"
      },
      "engines": {
        "node": ">=14.16"
      },
      "funding": {
        "url": "https://github.com/sindresorhus/file-type?sponsor=1"
      }
    },
    "node_modules/ieee754": {
      "version": "1.2.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/ieee754/-/ieee754-1.2.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-dcyqhDvX1C46lXZcVqCpK+FtMRQVdIMN6/Df5js2zouUsqG7I6sFxitIC+7KYK29KdXOLHdu9zL4sFnoVQnqaA==",
      "funding": [
        {
          "type": "github",
          "url": "https://github.com/sponsors/feross"
        },
        {
          "type": "patreon",
          "url": "https://www.patreon.com/feross"
        },
        {
          "type": "consulting",
          "url": "https://feross.org/support"
        }
      ]
    },
    "node_modules/inherits": {
      "version": "2.0.4",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits/-/inherits-2.0.4.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-k/vGaX4/Yla3WzyMCvTQOXYeIHvqOKtnqBduzTHpzpQZzAskKMhZ2K+EnBiSM9zGSoIFeMpXKxa4dYeZIQqewQ=="
    },
    "node_modules/lodash": {
      "version": "4.17.21",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash/-/lodash-4.17.21.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-v2kDEe57lecTulaDIuNTPy3Ry4gLGJ6Z1O3vE1krgXZNrsQ+LFTGHVxVjcXPs17LhbZVGedAJv8XZ1tvj5FvSg=="
    },
    "node_modules/lodash.snakecase": {
      "version": "4.1.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash.snakecase/-/lodash.snakecase-4.1.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-QZ1d4xoBHYUeuouhEq3lk3Uq7ldgyFXGBhg04+oRLnIz8o9T65Eh+8YdroUwn846zchkA9yDsDl5CVVaV2nqYw=="
    },
    "node_modules/peek-readable": {
      "version": "5.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/peek-readable/-/peek-readable-5.0.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-YtCKvLUOvwtMGmrniQPdO7MwPjgkFBtFIrmfSbYmYuq3tKDV/mcfAhBth1+C3ru7uXIZasc/pHnb+YDYNkkj4A==",
      "engines": {
        "node": ">=14.16"
      },
      "funding": {
        "type": "github",
        "url": "https://github.com/sponsors/Borewit"
      }
    },
    "node_modules/readable-stream": {
      "version": "3.6.2",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/readable-stream/-/readable-stream-3.6.2.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-9u/sniCrY3D5WdsERHzHE4G2YCXqoG5FTHUiCC4SIbr6XcLZBY05ya9EKjYek9O5xOAwjGq+1JdGBAS7Q9ScoA==",
      "dependencies": {
        "inherits": "^2.0.3",
        "string_decoder": "^1.1.1",
        "util-deprecate": "^1.0.1"
      },
      "engines": {
        "node": ">= 6"
      }
    },
    "node_modules/readable-web-to-node-stream": {
      "version": "3.0.2",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/readable-web-to-node-stream/-/readable-web-to-node-stream-3.0.2.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-ePeK6cc1EcKLEhJFt/AebMCLL+GgSKhuygrZ/GLaKZYEecIgIECf4UaUuaByiGtzckwR4ain9VzUh95T1exYGw==",
      "dependencies": {
        "readable-stream": "^3.6.0"
      },
      "engines": {
        "node": ">=8"
      },
      "funding": {
        "type": "github",
        "url": "https://github.com/sponsors/Borewit"
      }
    },
    "node_modules/safe-buffer": {
      "version": "5.2.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/safe-buffer/-/safe-buffer-5.2.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-rp3So07KcdmmKbGvgaNxQSJr7bGVSVk5S9Eq1F+ppbRo70+YeaDxkw5Dd8NPN+GD6bjnYm2VuPuCXmpuYvmCXQ==",
      "funding": [
        {
          "type": "github",
          "url": "https://github.com/sponsors/feross"
        },
        {
          "type": "patreon",
          "url": "https://www.patreon.com/feross"
        },
        {
          "type": "consulting",
          "url": "https://feross.org/support"
        }
      ]
    },
    "node_modules/streamsearch": {
      "version": "1.1.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/streamsearch/-/streamsearch-1.1.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-Mcc5wHehp9aXz1ax6bZUyY5afg9u2rv5cqQI3mRrYkGC8rW2hM02jWuwjtL++LS5qinSyhj2QfLyNsuc+VsExg==",
      "engines": {
        "node": ">=10.0.0"
      }
    },
    "node_modules/string_decoder": {
      "version": "1.3.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/string_decoder/-/string_decoder-1.3.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-hkRX8U1WjJFd8LsDJ2yQ/wWWxaopEsABU1XfkM8A+j0+85JAGppt16cr1Whg6KIbb4okU6Mql6BOj+uup/wKeA==",
      "dependencies": {
        "safe-buffer": "~5.2.0"
      }
    },
    "node_modules/strtok3": {
      "version": "7.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/strtok3/-/strtok3-7.0.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-pQ+V+nYQdC5H3Q7qBZAz/MO6lwGhoC2gOAjuouGf/VO0m7vQRh8QNMl2Uf6SwAtzZ9bOw3UIeBukEGNJl5dtXQ==",
      "dependencies": {
        "@tokenizer/token": "^0.3.0",
        "peek-readable": "^5.0.0"
      },
      "engines": {
        "node": ">=14.16"
      },
      "funding": {
        "type": "github",
        "url": "https://github.com/sponsors/Borewit"
      }
    },
    "node_modules/token-types": {
      "version": "5.0.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/token-types/-/token-types-5.0.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-Y2fmSnZjQdDb9W4w4r1tswlMHylzWIeOKpx0aZH9BgGtACHhrk3OkT52AzwcuqTRBZtvvnTjDBh8eynMulu8Vg==",
      "dependencies": {
        "@tokenizer/token": "^0.3.0",
        "ieee754": "^1.2.1"
      },
      "engines": {
        "node": ">=14.16"
      },
      "funding": {
        "type": "github",
        "url": "https://github.com/sponsors/Borewit"
      }
    },
    "node_modules/ts-mixer": {
      "version": "6.0.3",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/ts-mixer/-/ts-mixer-6.0.3.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-k43M7uCG1AkTyxgnmI5MPwKoUvS/bRvLvUb7+Pgpdlmok8AoqmUaZxUUw8zKM5B1lqZrt41GjYgnvAi0fppqgQ=="
    },
    "node_modules/tslib": {
      "version": "2.6.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/tslib/-/tslib-2.6.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-7At1WUettjcSRHXCyYtTselblcHl9PJFFVKiCAy/bY97+BPZXSQ2wbq0P9s8tK2G7dFQfNnlJnPAiArVBVBsfA=="
    },
    "node_modules/undici": {
      "version": "5.22.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/undici/-/undici-5.22.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-Ji2IJhFXZY0x/0tVBXeQwgPlLWw13GVzpsWPQ3rV50IFMMof2I55PZZxtm4P6iNq+L5znYN9nSTAq0ZyE6lSJw==",
      "dependencies": {
        "busboy": "^1.6.0"
      },
      "engines": {
        "node": ">=14.0"
      }
    },
    "node_modules/util-deprecate": {
      "version": "1.0.2",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/util-deprecate/-/util-deprecate-1.0.2.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-EPD5q1uXyFxJpCrLnCc1nHnq3gOa6DZBocAIiI2TaSCA7VCJ1UJDMagCzIkXNsUYfD1daK//LTEQ8xiIbrHtcw=="
    },
    "node_modules/ws": {
      "version": "8.13.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/ws/-/ws-8.13.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-x9vcZYTrFPC7aSIbj7sRCYo7L/Xb8Iy+pW0ng0wt2vCJv7M9HOMy0UoN3rr+IFC7hb7vXoqS+P9ktyLLLhO+LA==",
      "engines": {
        "node": ">=10.0.0"
      },
      "peerDependencies": {
        "bufferutil": "^4.0.1",
        "utf-8-validate": ">=5.0.2"
      },
      "peerDependenciesMeta": {
        "bufferutil": {
          "optional": true
        },
        "utf-8-validate": {
          "optional": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you need any more files, then please message me via comments and I will add it here. And, thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=message:+%27Unknown+interaction%27,+code:+10062+site:stackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a ***[mcve]*** of your attempt, noting input and expected output!

Comment: [So many possible dupes](https://www.google.com/search?q=message:+%27Unknown+interaction%27,+code:+10062+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: I won't get the error when I do the command in the right channel

Comment: I seem to have figured out the issue, adding `break;` just after the user is notified to post in a different channel fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `break;` after `` interaction.reply(`Error: You are in the wrong channel, please add the number in <#1129309284438638593\`); `` seems to fix the issue.

Comment: If you intend to answer your own question, then please remove 95% of the code in the question. If not, then please delete the whole thing

Comment: Yes, because if `channel.name` is not `phone-numbers`, you will call `interaction.reply` twice.

Comment: @mplungjan what do you mean? Which code to delete. Also, what do you mean by deleting the whole thing?

Comment: There is far too much irrelevant code in the question.